# "vendor" and "lib" not included in Rails.application.config.assets.paths for Rails 3.2 app converted from Rails 2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline

I upgraded an old Rails 2.3 application to version 3.2, and am in the process of switching my javascripts to use the Asset Pipeline.

Everything under `app/assets` is being included just fine. I had to create the directories under `vendor` by hand, but nothing is being picked up there. So I printed out the contents of `Rails.application.config.assets.paths` in the console, and sure enough the assets under `vendor` and `lib` are not in the path.

But I looked in another one of my existing Rails 3.2 applications, and sure enough `vendor` and `lib` are picked up fine.

But I grepped the `config` directory of that application for the word `vendor` and come up with nothing. So apparently `lib` and `vendor` get included implicitly somehow. I can't figure out how to add these.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just needed to restart the application, and those directories were picked up.